# Strapi Admin page not showing in local time format

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, strapi

I am using Strapi with MongoDB with successfully installed and run. My problem is Strapi Admin Panel shows date field in UTC format not in local time format. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Can you add more details on where the data is display.
In the content manager?

Comment: Thanks for comment. Yeah,it is in the Content Types section where list of data is showed in the table. I have checked also the return of API call, it returns exactly the same as in the table. I guess there should be some setting in the admin folder source. To be specific the problem is my local time is GMT+7 but Strapi shows UTC timezone which 7 hours different.